# Copying all objects from one instance to another at once JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, expression, instance, overriding

I wonder, how to make such a thing in JavaScript or is such a stuff even possible in it?

For example, I have:

```
// ps: this code is abstract and just an idea, not real one
var A = function( inputInstance ) {
    if ( inputInstance !== undefined )
        this = inputInstance;
    else 
        this = new B();
};
```

I'm interested in this possible or impossible stuff in JavaScript, because similar thing is possible in various functional programming languages, e.g. F#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233237.aspx

```
// This object expression specifies a System.Object but overrides the 
// ToString method.
let obj1 = { new System.Object() with member x.ToString() = "F#" }
printfn "%A" obj1
```

It can be very useful, if such thing could be possible in JavaScript, but I suggest it isn't possible, because I don't want to set several properties from one instance just for a object copy:

```
this.id = inputObject.id;
this.guid = inputObject.guid;
this.data = inputObject.data;
...
```

I don't want to declare each member of `inputObject`, I want to set/copy all existed properties from one instance to another just by one elegant line like in functional languages like F#, so is it possible in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You can, however, use a loop.

```
for (var key in inputInstance) {
    // Remove this if you want to copy inherited properties too
    if (inputInstance.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
        this[key] = inputInstance[key];
    }
}
```